# Задано n чисел. Определить, сколько среди них чётных

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, i = 1;
    cin >> n;
    int kol;
    kol = 1;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        int nums;
        cin >> nums;
        if (nums / 2 == 0) kol++;
    }
    cout << kol;

    return 0;
}
```

ребята, где ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

здесь должен стаять знак % вместо / `if (nums % 2 == 0) kol++;` и переменная `kol = 0`

Answer (score 3):

1. В этой задаче нужно проверять не частное `/`, а остатоко от деления `%`.

```
if (nums % 2 == 0) kol++;
```

Можно убрать `if` вовсе:

```
kol += !(nums%2);
```

2. Вы неверно инициализировали переменную `kol`, ведь изначально четных чисел вам не ввели, а значит их 0.

```
int kol = 0;
```

---

Рекомендации:

1. Переменную `nums` лучше назвать `num`, посколько ожидается ввод одного числа, а не списка чисел.
2. Называть переменные траслитом - плохая практика (переменную `kol` лучше назвать `even_count`).
3. Не нужно заранее объвлять переменную `i`.
4. Обычно итерируется не по `[1; n]`, а по `[0; n)`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, num;
    cin >> n;
    int even_count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> num;
        even_count += !(num%2);
    }
    cout << even_count;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i = 0 разве правда? отсчёт будет вестись от 0 до n, а значит если n будет равняться допустим 3, то чисел придётся вводить 4

Comment: переменную nums я назвал так, потому что числа вводиться будут через цикл, а значит их будет несколько. Разве я не прав?

Comment: @максим2009, до `n`, это означает **не включая n** (видите знак `<` в условии цикла).

Comment: @максим2009 ситуация выглядит так. `i=0, 0<3, cin; ++i, 1<3, cin; ++i, 2<3, cin; ++i, 3<3, выход из цикла`.

Comment: @максим2009 по поводу `nums`: число в данный момент вы вводите одно. `nums` будет уместно при использовании массивов, множеств и т.п.

Comment: @максим2009, imho, если назвать эту переменную (количество вводимых чисел) `limit`, то это всех устроит. (хотя, реальная польза от точности совпадения имени переменной с ее семантикой в коде,  сильно преувеличена)

Comment: @n1tr0xs а правда. не увидел, что вы написали i < n